# To display invalid email and password error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

In view: **login.php**

I am using this view file in two places one for user login and other displaying the invalid user and password message. Below i mentioned some code but it does not work. give me any suggestion regarding this problem.

```
 <div class="login-content">
/*
message to be displayed here:
 i try this one:<?php if(!(authentication($email,$password) == TRUE)){                          
echo "Invalid email address or password";
               }?>
  */
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('auth/check');?>" method="POST" class="margin-bottom-0" data-parsley-validate="true" onsubmit = "return Validate();" >
     <div class="form-group m-b-15">
    <input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php echo $language['Email'];?>" data-parsley-required='true' maxlength="95"/>
                            </div>
     <div class="form-group m-b-15">
    <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php echo $language['Password'];?>" data-parsley-required='true' maxlength="95"/>
     </div>
```

In Controller: **Auth.php**

This is a `function` for checking the user validation. I want to display a message using this `function` in `else` condition.

```
public function check(){

    $email      = $this->input->post('txtemail');
    $password   = $this->encrypt($this->input->post('txtpassword'));
    $this->load->model('cmsuser_model');
    $user = $this->cmsuser_model->authentication($email,$password);

    if(!is_null($user))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $user);
        $this->session->set_userdata('profile_image',$user->image);
        $this->session->set_userdata('is_manager','0');


        $this->load->model('association_model');
        $table = '';
        $limit = '';
        $order_by = '';
        $group_by = '';
        $start = '';
        $fields = '';
        $where = array();
        $where['created_by'] = $this->session->userdata['user']->cmsuid;
        $dt = $this->association_model->get_all($fields, $where, $table, $limit, $order_by, $group_by, $start);
        $this->session->set_userdata('ass_id', $dt[0]['ass_id']); 

        redirect(base_url('index.php/welcome'), 'refresh');
    }
    else{
  //Browser redirect to this else condition but i am not able to display message in `view(login.php)` file.
    redirect(base_url('index.php/auth/login'), 'refresh');
        }
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function check(){

    $email      = $this->input->post('txtemail');
    $password   = $this->encrypt($this->input->post('txtpassword'));
    $this->load->model('cmsuser_model');
    $user = $this->cmsuser_model->authentication($email,$password);

    if(!is_null($user))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $user);
        $this->session->set_userdata('profile_image',$user->image);
        $this->session->set_userdata('is_manager','0');


        $this->load->model('association_model');
        $table = '';
        $limit = '';
        $order_by = '';
        $group_by = '';
        $start = '';
        $fields = '';
        $where = array();
        $where['created_by'] = $this->session->userdata['user']->cmsuid;
        $dt = $this->association_model->get_all($fields, $where, $table, $limit, $order_by, $group_by, $start);
        $this->session->set_userdata('ass_id', $dt[0]['ass_id']); 

        redirect(base_url('index.php/welcome'), 'refresh');
    }
    else{
      $url=echo base_url('login.php').'?status=err';
      redirect($url, 'refresh');
//this will redirect you to the login page with the parameter status in the url
        }
    exit;
}
```

in login.php View File

```
<?php
   $satatus = $_GET['status'];
   if($status == 'err'){
?>
//add this div right above the login section
<div>Wrong Username/Password !!</div>
    <div class="login-content">
/*
message to be displayed here:
 i try this one:<?php if(!(authentication($email,$password) == TRUE)){                          
echo "Invalid email address or password";
               }?>
  */
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('auth/check');?>" method="POST" class="margin-bottom-0" data-parsley-validate="true" onsubmit = "return Validate();" >
     <div class="form-group m-b-15">
    <input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php echo $language['Email'];?>" data-parsley-required='true' maxlength="95"/>
                            </div>
     <div class="form-group m-b-15">
    <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="<?php echo $language['Password'];?>" data-parsley-required='true' maxlength="95"/>
     </div>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: is it segment based URL?  {LInk}(https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: Yes, the URL is the domain_name/controller_name/function_name

Comment: To display the error message you need to add a parameter in the url like i have done : "?status=err" <- concatenate this at the end. Then you can show the error message in view based on this parameter which will be concatenated in case the user entry is not present in the db

Comment: i did not get the '?status=err' part.

Comment: <?php echo site_url('auth/check');?>  This is what you have used in your code right? This takes u to the function check in auth controller. From where you call a model to see if the entry exists? I am just saying from model create a $url like this : <?php echo site_url('auth/check').'?status=err';?>  Add this 'status=err' parameter when you are not able to find the user entry in the database and redirect to this $url at the end. Then in view file u can use this parameter to display the error message.

Comment: ?status=err This is how you write a parameter in the url by using a "?" mark then the name of the parameter and then "="sign and then the value of the parameter

Comment: i am little confuse in defining variable in div view.i mean how to pass the parameter to display the message.

Comment: my boss saying everything is fine but i have to work in Auth.php the else condition to display error message.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Did the changes. I hope it solved your purpose.